# SCP hanging when uploading large amount of files

Tags: scp

I am transferring a large amount of files, about 17,000, from my computer to an EC2 instance with an S3 bucket mounted to it.

For some reason, I only ever get somewhere between 200 to 400 files uploaded before the connection seems to quit.

I got the following error:
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
lost connection

What can I do to get all these files uploaded successfully?

Comment: One *possible* cause of the issue: if I remember correctly, SCP & SFTP require servers time be synchronized within 15 minutes. If you are running a long operation, perhaps the connection may need to be re-initialized every so often.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Why would scp and SFTP require time syncing?

Comment: Are you behind carrier grade NAT?  As an aside, building an ssh command to compress, ship and decompress is a lot faster on small files because there is much less back-and-forth chatter+latency  issues.  something like **tar -cz /path/to/files | ssh user@dest.site "cd /path; tar -xz"**

Comment: Time is used as part of the connection protocol to prevent a party-in-the-middle recording login and using it later to connect.